# How to do a distinct on Azure Application Insights Analytics and then project few variables from the new distinct set

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have a query to find out the distinct user Ids and their country, agency name, city code who use a specific product version.
How do I list the properties successfully?
Below query doesn't have filter out the unique users.

customEvents
| where customDimensions.["Product Version"] == "7.4" 
| where timestamp between(datetime("2018-12-01T00:00:00.000Z")..datetime("2018-12-02T00:00:00.000Z"))
| project client_CountryOrRegion, user_Id, customDimensions.["Agency Name"], customDimensions.["Pseudo City Code"], customDimensions.["Product Version"]

Comment: Hello, if the answer works for you, could yo please help mark it as answer? thanks.

Answer (score 11):

**update**:

Please use alias when use tostring() method. And then in the project command, use the alias instead of the column name.

See my test result as below:

[image]

---

Before the project syntax, please use `summarize count() by client_CountryOrRegion, user_Id, customDimensions.["Agency Name"], customDimensions.["Pseudo City Code"], customDimensions.["Product Version"]` , then use project to output the properties your like.

Completed code like below:

```
customEvents
| where customDimensions.["Product Version"] == "7.4" 
| where timestamp between(datetime("2018-12-01T00:00:00.000Z")..datetime("2018-12-02T00:00:00.000Z")) 
| summarize count() by client_CountryOrRegion, user_Id, customDimensions.["Agency Name"], customDimensions.["Pseudo City Code"], customDimensions.["Product Version"]
| project client_CountryOrRegion, user_Id, customDimensions.["Agency Name"], customDimensions.["Pseudo City Code"], customDimensions.["Product Version"]
```

Please let me if any issues.

Comment: Thanks. I get below error when using this. "Summarize group key 'customDimensions_Agency Name' is of a 'dynamic' type. Please use an explicit cast (for example, 'summarize ... by tostring(customDimensions_Agency Name)') as grouping by a 'dynamic' type is not supported."

Comment: If I use 'tostring' it returns an execution error on project command line.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you should use alias when use tostring(), like Agency_name=tostring(customDimensions.["Agency Name"]). Then in the project command, use the alias like: project Agency_name. Details refer to my updated answer.

Comment: @user3669982, do you have any more issues? if it works, please help mark it as an answer. Thanks.